# Taylor expension of a simple integral

Tags: integration, taylor-series

I'm trying to derive some weights expression for a boosting algorithm on a L2-ISE loss function, and i have trouble with the taylor expension.

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two densities from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $R$. Denote by $L$ the loss from estimating $g$ by $f$ i.e the functional :

$$L(f) = \int \left(f(x) - g(x)\right)^2\; dx$$

I am interested in the first order taylor expension for $L((1-\epsilon) f_1 + \epsilon f_2) = L(f_1 + \epsilon (f_2 - f_1)) $ for small $\epsilon > 0$, so i write :

$$L(f_1 + \epsilon (f_2 - f_1)) \approx L(f_1) + \epsilon\frac{dL}{df_1}(f_1) (f_2 - f_1)$$

Then i write the derivative of the loss as :

$$\frac{dL}{df_1}(f_1) = \int 2(f_1(x) - g(x)) \; dx$$

Which clearly gives $0$ since $f_1$ and $g$ are densities ! So the loss function is flat everywhere ? Where am i wrong ?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but that last derivative is not $\int 2(f_1-g(x))dx$, but rather the operator mapping, say,  $w$ to $\int 2(f_1-g(x))w(x)dx$. In any case it should be a linear form rather than just a real number.

Comment: I agree with Pierre. Intuitively, $f_1$ is not one variable but rather represents infinitely many variables. So the derivative with respect to $f_1$ is really a gradient best written as a linear functional.

Comment: The functional is a polynomial map of degree 2 wrto the variabile $f$ in $L^2$, so the answer is immediate

Comment: So do you guys agree with the conclusion we had with Michael (on the first answer) giving the gradient as the functional :

$$\omega \mapsto \int (f_1(y)-g(y))\omega(y) dy \text{  ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be mathematically precise, you'd have to say a bit more about what space you're doing this on and whether you're thinking of a Frechet derivative or a Gateaux derivative, etc., but for practical purposes, you can think of functions like you would of components of a vector, just labeled by a continuous index instead of a discrete one. Then you have the basic functional derivative
$$
\frac{\delta f(x) }{\delta f(y)} = \delta (x-y)
$$
i.e., a Kronecker $\delta $ is correspondingly replaced by a Dirac $\delta $. So then your Taylor expansion is
\begin{eqnarray}
L[f_1 +\epsilon (f_2 -f_1)] &=& L[f_1 ] +\epsilon \int dy \frac{\delta L[f_1 ]}{\delta f_1 (y) } (f_2 (y) -f_1 (y)) \\
&=& L[f_1 ] + \epsilon \int dy\ 2(f_1 (y) - g(y)) (f_2 (y) -f_1 (y))
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: So the gradient will be the functional : 

$$\omega \mapsto \int (f_1(y)-g(y))\omega(y) dy \text{  ?}$$

Comment: Well, we're really in non-standard language territory here, and you can think of different notions of "gradient". If you want to stick to the vector analogy, the gradient is just the $\delta L[f_1 ] / \delta f_1 (y) = 2(f_1 (y)-g(y))$ - a "vector" indexed by $y$. In a Taylor expansion, you take the scalar product of this with your increment "vector" $\Delta f(y) = \epsilon (f_2 (y)-f_1 (y))$, which includes summing over $y$, i.e. $\int dy$. In the end, this is the same as saying you're constructing a linear functional applied to $\Delta f$. You might call that "gradient" instead.

Comment: We're streeeeeeeeeeetching language here. Maybe we should stop before it breaks.

Comment: Ok I got the scalar product part. Indeed, the function I wrote is more the "L2-scalar product with the gradient". Thanks for taking the time :)